# Do I need a transit visa in Switzerland?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, syrian-citizens, gva

I'm a green card holder and I have a Syrian passport, my main destination is Lebanon and I'm going through Geneva airport. Do I need a transit visa?

Comment: No, if airside transit is possible, the green card exempts you from the airport transit visa requirement, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area for details.